# ASP.NET parameter/variable in both app Settings and app Build Events

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, build

In ASP.NET, we have Application Settings, and we have Application Pre/Post Build Events. Is it possible to access a Setting from the Pre Build Event? Or is it possible to inject the value of a Setting from the Pre Build Event?

Full context:

I have an Angular app embedded in an ASP.NET 4 Web API app. That is, my app is structured like this:

```
+ Solution
| - Project
|   + Properties
|   + AngularApp
|   | + dist
|   | + e2e
|   | + src
|   | - (etc)
|   + App_Start
|   + Model
|   + Global.asax
|   - Web.config
- ProjectTest
```

I have some URL rewrite rules so that any request `website.com/x` that doesn't refer to one of my Controllers will instead be redirected to `website.com/AngularApp/dist/AngularApp/x`. Everything I've described so far is working great.

The trouble is, this app is not being deployed to the root of the domain; it's being deployed to a subdirectory of the domain. (i.e. `website.com/app` instead of `website.com`). Three different portions of my app need to know that this new subdirectory should be considered root - the Angular app needs to have this configured as root, the rewrite rules need to incorporate this, and a certain pieces of C# code also needs to know about this new root (I'll save you the details here). Currently, I've had to specify this subdirectory in both the Pre Build Events (which are building the Angular app) and the Web.config (which controls my rewrite rules) and the Settings (which are accessed by my aforementioned C# code). It'd be better if I could have a single configuration that they all pulled from. My above question would at least allow the combination of two of these disparate three configurations.

Comment: Did you think about copying/moving client files into some appropriate directory instead of URL-rewriting them? Such an operation can easily be done using MSBuild or even post-build event.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not to do with any build events, it's rather to bootstrap your angular app with some values from hosting ASP view.
If I understand your app layout correctly, you might be able to push some variables onto a Razor view as plain javascript that would get picked up by Angular upon startup.

#### Model

```cs
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModel() { Path = "/app/1/test" });
    }
}
```

#### View

```html
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <h1>Server-side path @Model.Path</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clientSidePath = "@Model.Path"; @* Razor happily renders values into javascript blocks *@
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Client-side path ' + clientSidePath;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The absolute minimum Dotnet fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pO2wHN. For simplicity sake I opted for AngularJS (which is probably not the exact version you use) but similar approach should work with recent Angular as well.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think of doing it this way. Admittedly, making a whole Razor template & controller just to inject a property into my Angular app is a little more complex than I was hoping for. But it does achieve my goal. Thanks for the idea; let me think about it.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you host the SPA from somewhere like a razor page.

Comment: Nah, I'm only using the "API" part of ASP.NET; I haven't even imported the Razor Pages library. Instead IIS just serves my Angular app as normal static files. And that's why I'm not sure whether or not your solution - although it's good - is the right solution for me. Definitely appreciate it though!

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more specifics on what your setup is? I'm mostly interested in how you build your angular app but anything that you think is relevant might help

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to leave you hanging. I've updated the question with a little more context, but your answer is still applicable.